# How to highlight text in filtered listView on text listener in android studio?

Tags: java, android, listview, addtextchangedlistener

I have gone through various links, where highlighting textview is given but I need it for list.

My search method:

```
public void addTextListener() {

        inputSearchMain.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

                query = query.toString().toLowerCase();

                final ArrayList<CategoryModel.CategoryList> filteredList = new ArrayList<CategoryModel.CategoryList>();


                for (int i = 0; i < result_Category.size(); i++) {

                    final String text = result_Category.get(i).getCategory_name().toLowerCase();
                    if (text.contains(query)) {
                        //if(text.startsWith(query)

                        filteredList.add(result_Category.get(i));

                    }
                }

                mainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(CardViewActivity.this));
                mainAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterMain(filteredList);
                mainRecyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
                mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // data set changed
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I use the following piece of code to highlight text in list?

Code I want to use:

```
public static CharSequence highlight(String search, String originalText) {
        String normalizedText = Normalizer.normalize(originalText, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "").toLowerCase();
        int start = normalizedText.indexOf(search);
        if (start <= 0) {
            return originalText;
        } else {
            Spannable highlighted = new SpannableString(originalText);
            while (start > 0) {
                int spanStart = Math.min(start, originalText.length());
                int spanEnd = Math.min(start + search.length(), originalText.length());
                highlighted.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                start = normalizedText.indexOf(search, spanEnd);
            }
            return highlighted;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put Your RecyclerViewAdapterMain implementation. I think you have to return String from highlight method in th form of html string. Use this string with Html.fromHtml() to display it in text view.